# Add new selection with options from database

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, variables, selection

I have a function to add a new selection using button in the table with ID="maTable"

```
<button type="button" onclick ="addNew()"> Add More Agent</button>
```

Using JS :

```
 function Addnew(){
 var table=document.getElementById("maTable");
 var row=table.insertRow([table.rows.length]-1);
 var len=(table.rows.length);
 var newid="agentID"+len;
 var newida="agentGroup"+len;

 var cell1=row.insertCell;
 var cell2=row.insertCell;
 var cell3=row.insertCell;

 var new_optionAgent =
 "<select class=\"opsi\"id="'+newida+'">"
 +"<option selected=\"selected\"disabled=\"disabled\">Agent<\/option>"
 +"<option value=\"agentA\">Agent A<\/option>"
 +"<option value=\"agentB\">Agent B<\/option>"
 +"<option value=\"agentC\">Agent C<\/option>"
 +"<option value=\"agentD\">Agent D<\/option>"
 +"<\/select>"

cell1.innerHTML="Choose Agent" +" "+len;
cell2.innerHTML=":";
cell3.innerHTML= new_optionAgent;
}
```

With this I can get a button that will generate a new selection with 4 options (it works). But now come the problem when I want to change the option with the list from database. Im using php and postgres database. I made the code for the one that isn't generated from the "AddNew" button yet :

```
<?php
        $que=pg_query("SELECT agentname FROM Agent");

        echo "<select name=\"agentname1\"class=\"opsi\" id=\"agentGroup1\" required>";
        echo "<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\"disabled='disabled'>Agent</option>";
        While($row=pg_fetch_array($que))
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['agentname'].'"> '.$row['agentname'].'</option>';
        }
        echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

Now I want to make the "AddNew" button that generate a selection with option list from database. I have combined the php code with variable "new_optionAgent" by adding "\" to some symbols. but it doesnt work.

I combine like this

```
    var new_optionAgent =
'<\?php
\$que=pg_query(\"SELECT agentname FROM Agent\")\;

echo \'<select name=\\\"agentname1\\\"class=\\\"opsi\\\" id=\\\"agentGroup1\\\" required>\'\;
echo \'<option value=\\\"\\\" selected=\\\"selected\\\"disabled=\\\'disabled\\\'>Agent</option>\'\;
While(\$row=pg_fetch_array(\$que))
{
    echo \'<option value=\"\'\.$row[\'agentname\']\.\'\"> \'\.$row[\'agentname\']\.\'</option>\'\;
}
echo \"<\/select>\"\;
\?>'
```

this combination is seems very wrong, Any help? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because the escaped backslashes is used by PHP for escaping the double quotes. So you will need to add another set of backslases and escape those, or use a single quote string in PHP:

```
<?php
    $que=pg_query("SELECT agentname FROM Agent");

    echo '<select name=\"agentname1\"class=\"opsi\" id=\"agentGroup1\" required>';
    echo '<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\"disabled=\'disabled\'>Agent</option>';
    While($row=pg_fetch_array($que))
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['agentname'].'"> '.$row['agentname'].'</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

## Edit

You can't inline PHP inside a Javascript variable like that. Try this:

```
<?php
    $que=pg_query("SELECT agentname FROM Agent");

    $whateverYouWannaCallThisString = '';

    $whateverYouWannaCallThisString .= '<select name=\"agentname1\"class=\"opsi\" id=\"agentGroup1\" required>';
    $whateverYouWannaCallThisString .= '<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\"disabled=\'disabled\'>Agent</option>';
    While($row=pg_fetch_array($que))
    {
        $whateverYouWannaCallThisString .= '<option value="'.$row['agentname'].'"> '.$row['agentname'].'</option>';
    }
    $whateverYouWannaCallThisString .= "</select>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var new_optionAgent = "<?php echo $whateverYouWannaCallThisString; ?>";
</script>
```

## More info on escaping

The whole reason you are escaping characters is because you are using characters that surrounds the string itself. E.g: If you are defining a string with double quotes `"` like this: `var myString = "Yolo"` and you want to have double quotes `"` in that string like this: `var myString = "Dude, wheres "my" car"` then you need to escape the double quotes `"` thats inside that string like this: `var myString = "Dude, wheres \"my\" car"`.

The same applies to PHP

//Edit :
I edited the variable :

```
 var new_optionAgent =
 <?php echo json_encode($whateverYouWannaCallThisString); ?>;
```

and it works :)

Comment: so i just add backslash for every ' " . $ ? and \ ,,,, am i right?

Comment: If you are using a single quoted string you only need to escape the single quotes, and you only need to escape double quotes if you are using double quoted strings.

Comment: add another set of escape blacksles for double quoted string? like ; echo \'<select name=\\"agentname1\\"class=\\"opsi\\" id=\\"agentGroup1\\" required>\';

Comment: I did include what should be a working example in the answer. To get it to work in PHP with a double quoted string you first need to escape a backslash and then escape the double quote: `\\\"`

Comment: @ Joachim I did it. it gave no error. but it doesnt work as well. I am afraid i was wrong in giving blacksles for the other symbols. what other symbols must and must not I give backsles?

Comment: It really depends on where are you echoing these strings. You could provide more of your code in your question so we can better see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Edited. like I wrote b4. i would like to add new selection with option list taken from database

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't magically figure what is wrong. You need to provide me with more info than just *It doesn't work*. You need to understand why you are escaping characters in order to figure this one out.

Comment: I tried the php code itself, it works. the problem is in the variable

Comment: i modified the variable    var new_optionAgent =
  <?php echo json_encode($whateverYouWannaCallThisString); ?>; and it works. the problem solved. Thanks man. appreciate u a lot :)

Comment: I edited ur answer if u dont mind. and mark it as the answer